# Laravel 5.8 Class XXX does not exists while injection

Tags: php, dependency-injection, laravel-5.8

I have a class App/Model/BookService which needs to be injected inside the controller method as dependency injection. Controller code looks like:

```
use App\Model\BookSearchFilterService;

...

public function index(BookSearchFilterService $searchFilterService)
{
    ...

    $searchFilterService->setFilter($book);

    ...
}
```

PhpStorm is able to show me the class if I click on the class name, but Laravel throws me an error Class **App\Model\BookSearchFilterService** does not exist. How is it possible? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are the filename and class the same? I assume they are loaded with Composer and they are PSR-4 compatible?

Comment: I am not sure if this could be the reason but yes the file name is the same as class name. Not the directory structure but I have another class in the same dir and it is possible to inject the class. Is there some cache or something which needs to be refreshed?

Comment: Did you try to refresh the autoload using `composer dump`?

Comment: First time I hear about it. But it did not help.

Comment: The default for Laravel is not to have a folder called "Model". Have you created this folder yourself, or have you got the namespace wrong at the top? Also check in BookSearchFilterService.php and check you have named the class correctly and have `namespace App\Model;`. Also in your post you start by saying it's called `BookService`. Which is it?

Comment: So your class name is `BookSearchFilterService` within the `App\Model` namespace and its filename is `app/Model/BookSearchFilterService.php`? Because you're writing about `App/Model/BookService`..

Comment: No the path is App/Model/Services/BookSearchFilterService.php It contains BookSearchFilterService class which does not exists.... The BookService is the class which works well and it is the same pattern. I dont know where is the difference between this two classes. One them works another cant be find.

Comment: So as I changed the namespace to App/Model/Services/BookSearchFilterService it works. BUT how is it possible that class with namepsace App/Model/BookService works within this namespace and BookSearchFilterService does not if they are in the same App/Model/Services dirctory?